# Bash: Remove ALL special characters from end of variable (not just CR or LF)

Tags: bash

I have some text files and getting the first line(s) into a variable using `var=$(head -n 1 "$@")`, however the variable contains special charaters that I want removed (ASCII 1-31).

Is there a quick way to strip the end of a variable from ASCII codes 1-31? I've used `${var//[^[:ascii:]]/}` and `var="${var//[$'\t\r\n']}"` already, however I need ASCII 1-31 removed from the end in a simple way (not just CF/LF/Tab/FF/etc.).

Comment: I found this, but don't know which applies to bash https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Strip_control_codes_and_extended_characters_from_a_string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a character class for control characters – quote from the [grep manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#index-cntrl-character-class):

> `[:cntrl:]`
>
> Control characters. In ASCII, these characters have octal codes 000 through 037, and 177 (DEL). In other character sets, these are the equivalent characters, if any.

So, you could do

```sh
var=${var//[[:cntrl:]]}
```